# Lightweight self-hosted synchronization tool

Tags: file-synchronization, self-hosted, synchronization

The need here is to be able to sync a few "mounts" on multiple devices, desktop and, if possible, mobile (Android + SailfishOS).

There are a few existing tools, such as OwnCloud and NextCloud, which are both absolutely *overkill* and pretty painful to set up/maintain.

The tool should provide this "mounts" service, with an optional *simple* web interface, and *nothing more*.

Ideally, the tool should be a runnable archive/binary, and not rely on interpreters such as PHP, Node, or Python.

Edit: Just to be clear, some additional things that make other questions unrelated:

I'm not searching for a tool that "can" do that, and more.

I'm *specifically* searching for a tool that can *only* do synchronization, I'm not even interested in a web UI to manage the files online, and want something as simple as possible to use.

Comment: Not using it myself, hence no answer – but while waiting for one, take a look at SyncThing. That seems to match your description almost perfectly.

Comment: Syncthing is advertized as a "P2P file sync. tool", and I couldn't find a documentation to run a node as a server. Can you do so?

Comment: There are a couple of good vids on it, linked from the app's entry in [my corresponding list](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_sync#group_1089) (next to the official client; the list has 2 more).

Comment: Thanks, @Izzy, after setting it up, it perfectly matched what I was aiming for.

Comment: Couldn't hope for more – and thanks for letting me know! // Could you please update your answer to contain a link to where the software you used can be found (homepage for PC-side download, F-Droid/Play-Store for Android end)? To encourage you, I upvote in advance :)

Comment: Added my full list, as you requested @Izzy

Comment: Thanks a lot! Already upvoted as promised :) Glad you found a perfect solution – enjoy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried Pydio, which was a nightmare to set up right, and its compatibility with MariaDB only was a serious downside, so I put that solution aside.

As @Izzy mentioned, SyncThing is a good fit, even for a server <> clients architecture, as it'll act as a central P2P node on which every device will connect.

Its compatibility with a very wide variety of systems also make it a very appealing choice, and its lightness is also a good point to note.

So, for a lightweight file-synchronization-only tool, SyncThing was the right fit.

This is the list of softwares I went as clients.

- SailfishOS: [syncthing-bin](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/syncthing-bin).
- ArchLinux: [syncthing-bin](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/syncthing-bin), running as a daemon, with a small shortcut added to my i3bar configuration.
- Android: [Syncthing](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.nutomic.syncthingandroid/)
- Windows: [SyncTrazor](https://github.com/canton7/SyncTrayzor), but I may move to Syncthing-GTK, as it does not look very active.